# Invalid protocol version error when adding a device to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to create a new device identity in the identity registry in my Azure IoT Hub. I follow the steps outlined [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/#create-a-device-identity).

But when i add a new device on registry :

```
device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId));
```

I get an exception with this message :

> ErrorCode:InvalidProtocolVersion;Invalid protocol version:2016-04-30

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might is because the version of the dll you are referencing are not matching the version of hub.

The new hub version that has just been released uses the pre-release version of Microsoft.Azure.Devices. Check which version you are using. If possible add the screenshot of your nuget packages.

Comment: I upgraded from 1.0.8 to 1.1.0-preview-002 and it works like a charm now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: how do you tell the version of the hub?

Comment: What I meant was the new IOT hub release with the device management capabilities which  came sometime in April. If you have created your iot hub after that release then you need updated dll. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-device-management-get-started/